# Importing cmap file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, import, mapping

I have a cmap file that I want to import in QGIS and use as the color ramp for my map layer. How do I do this?

Comment: What is a cmap file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reach out to the customer support of the program that created the cmap file.  Or look into export options.  I'm not familiar with the filetype myself.